# Hide zero value data labels for excel charts (with category name)

Tags: excel, graph, hide, zero

I'm trying to hide data labels for an excel chart if the value for a category is zero. I already formatted it with a custom data label format with `#%;;;`

[image: Chart with format code #%;;;]

As you can see the data label for C4 and C5 is still visible, but I just need the category name if there is a value.

Do you have any tips?

Comment: Excel charts ignore na() while plotting 0 in a series, so try changing 0 values to na() then it may sort the issue - works for my overlaid series...

Comment: Yes worked fine for me thx :)